# Convert System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string,T> into IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, collections, ienumerable

What is the most efficient way to convert a

```
System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string,Contact>
```

into a

```
IEnumerable<Contact>
```

The consumer of IEnumerable is an MVC view which will want to display the items in the order in which they were stored in System.Collections.Generic.SortedList

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SortedList.Values` or `SortedList.GetValueList` (only in the non-generic version) is just what you need.

Comment: +1 - Yes - just for Journeyman - this will return an IList<Contact> which implements IEnumerable<Contact>